# Custom Payment Module:How Can i Pass smarty variables with in paymentoptions hook in prestashop 1.7?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am worried about how can i pass smarty variable in paymentoptions hook in prestashop 1.7 version and get that variables in payment page.

In prestashop 1.7 paymentoptions  hooks looks like this,

```
 public function hookPaymentOptions($params)
    {
        $payment_options = new PaymentOption();
            $action_text = $this->l('Pay by Credit Card with Stripe Payment');
            /*$payment_options->setLogo(Media::getMediaPath(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$this->name.'/views/img/card.png'));*/
            $payment_options->setCallToActionText($action_text);
            $payment_options->setAction($this->context->link->getModuleLink($this->name, 'confirmation', array(), true));
            $payment_options->setModuleName($this->name);
            $payment_options->setAdditionalInformation($this->context->smarty->fetch('module:stripepay/views/templates/hook/checkout.tpl'));
            $payments_options[] = $payment_options;

         return $payments_options;
    }
```

with in this hook how can i pass this secure_key ="FGDWFGF$#%#%!$" values in checkout.tpl files for making successful payments.

Now i have keep this values as static.

Please anybody knows this please assist with this.

I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use $_SESSION if you just only have to preserve it for later.
For checkout.tpl you should use hookPayment($params) instead, it's meant to populate a TPL and it's retrocompatible with older versions :

```
public function hookPayment($params)
{

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array('myvar'=>'thevalue'));
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'checkout.tpl');

}
```

Comment: In prestashop 1.7 hookpayment hooks is not accepted in paymentmodule.They use alternate for paymentoptions hooks